# iTerm2: Is it possible to open the current line in a text editor?

Tags: iterm2

When writing long commands, it is quite time consuming to use the arrow keys to edit the line.

Is there any method where I can use a keyboard shortcut to open everything on the current line (that has not yet been executed) in a fast text editor (sublime), edit the line, and then save/close and have the edits written back out to the terminal ready to be executed?

Comment: Usually, I write everything in a text editor and then copy/paste it to the terminal - this way you can easily edit the (long) command (or have multiple versions of it with different parameters) - if a series of commands are to be executed in sequence, you can always create a shell script and run that

Answer (score 13):

iTerm2 has a really nice feature for this use case: the **composer**. It opens a native text field, where you can type more easily than in the command-line interface.

You can open it from the menu (*View > Composer*), or using the shortcut <kbd>⇧⌘.</kbd>.

[image: iTerm2 with the composer open]

Comment: Shames that iTerms2 cannot move current context into the Composer, or there is something I dont know?

Comment: What do you mean by “context”? Is it what’s currently written after the prompt? If that’s the case, I’m not aware of any way to do it automatically.

Comment: It can, you just need to enable Shell Integration: https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html.

Comment: It took a half of eternity to notice the full stop character in the shortcut )) Not blaming anyone, only myself

Answer (score 5):

If you're using bash, then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> will open the current line in your default text editor. (It uses the `$EDITOR` environment variable to determine which editor to use iirc)